# Failed to open stream when moving magento site from sub directory to root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento-1.8

I've just gone through the process of moving a urba instance of Magento from a /urba dir into the root dir but it's still looking for files in the /urba dir.

I've updated the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url values, cleared /var/cache and /var/session double checked the .htaccess RewriteBase,  updated all my folders and files to root folder

When I press save config the admin panel of magento also disappears from the link

Now when i am opening my site link

http://urbanunity.co.uk/

It automatically redirects me to

http://urbanunity.co.uk/downloader/

with following errors

```
Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/code/local:/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/code/community:/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/code/core:/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/lib:.:/usr/local/php5_4/lib/php') in /home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/Mage.php on line 51

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/code/local:/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/code/community:/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/code/core:/home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/lib:.:/usr/local/php5_4/lib/php') in /home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/Mage.php on line 51

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/content/07/12442607/html/Urba/app/Mage.php on line 54
```

I have done changes in index.php files

`$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';`

to

`$mageFilename = 'cart/app/Mage.php';`

Using magento version `1.8.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Magento Docs for moving Magento folder?

[Magento Doc - Move Magento to Another Directory](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/move_magento_to_another_directory)

Comment: No followed this method https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/move_magento_to_another_directory